# Freezing headers/columns CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

This is my web template. I want to freeze the header part and also the "#" and "Rank" columns. Vertical scrolling should scroll through the rows only and horizontal scrolling should scroll through Header3 onwards.

```
        |     #    |   Rank  | Header3 | Header4 | Header5 | Header6 |
  []    |    #1    |  Rank1  | 
  []    |    #2    |  Rank2  | 
  []    |    #3    |  Rank3  | 
  []    |    #4    |  Rank4  | 
  []    |    #5    |  Rank5  | 
  []    |    #6    |  Rank6  |
```

I would think there should be separate  tags with different css styles. One of which the headers css style should contain `position:fixed`.

```
<div class="form-horizontal table-responsive table-masterinput">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped" id="whatever">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th class="text-center">#</th>
                <th class="text-center">Rank</th>
                <th class="text-center">Header3</th>
                <th class="text-center">Header4</th>
                <th class="text-center">Header5</th>
                <th class="text-center">Header6</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{
                var index = 1;
                if (Model != null && Model.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var items in Model)
                    {
                        total += 1;

                        <tr class="checkCountData" id=@("item" + index)>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="@items.Id" id="@items.Id" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <label data-Id="@items.Id" style="width: 100px; text-align: center" class="inputRank" name="inputRank">@items.RANK_CODE</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>Item3</td>
                            <td>Item4</td>
                            <td>Item5</td>
                            <td>Item6</td>
                        </tr>

                        index++;
                    }
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is my css:

```
.table-masterinput {
    overflow-x: auto;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 300px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 180px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

try this with jquery and css or try this [fiddle check here](https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/o0hqx6mc/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tbody').scroll(function(e) { //detect a scroll event on the tbody
   /*
    Setting the thead left value to the negative valule of tbody.scrollLeft will make it track the movement
    of the tbody element. Setting an elements left value to that of the tbody.scrollLeft left makes it maintain    it's relative position at the left of the table.    
    */
    $('thead').css("left", -$("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the thead relative to the body scrolling
    $('thead th:nth-child(1), thead th:nth-child(2)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the first cell of the header
    $('tbody td:nth-child(1), tbody td:nth-child(2)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the first column of tdbody
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}


/*thead*/
thead {
  position: relative;
  display: block; /*seperates the header from the body allowing it to be positioned*/
  width: 700px;
  overflow: visible;
}

thead th {
  background-color: #99a;
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

thead th:nth-child(1) {/*first cell in the header*/
  position: relative;
  display: block; /*seperates the first cell in the header from the header*/
  background-color: #88b;
}

thead th:nth-child(2) {/*first cell in the header*/
  position: relative;
  background-color: #88b;
}


/*tbody*/
tbody {
  position: relative;
  display: block; /*seperates the tbody from the header*/
  width: 700px;
  height: 239px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

tbody td {
  background-color: #bbc;
  min-width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {  /*the first cell in each tr*/
  position: relative;
  display: block; /*seperates the first column from the tbody*/
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #99a;
}
tbody tr td:nth-child(2) {  /*the first cell in each tr*/
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #99a;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Header1</th>
        <th>Header2</th>
        <th>Header3</th>
        <th>Header4</th>
        <th>Header5</th>
        <th>Header6</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>#1</td>
        <td>Rank1</td>
        <td>Cheshire</td>
        <td>52</td>
        <td>Brewer</td>
        <td>£47,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>#2</td>
        <td>Rank2</td>
        <td>Cumbria</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>Shepherdess</td>
        <td>£28,000</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>#3</td>
        <td>Rank3</td>
        <td>Wiltshire</td>
        <td>57</td>
        <td>Musician</td>
        <td>£124,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>#4</td>
        <td>Rank4</td>
        <td>Worchestershire</td>
        <td>48</td>
        <td>Naturalist</td>
        <td>£65,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>#5</td>
        <td>Rank5</td>
        <td>Hertfordshire</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>Pharmasist</td>
        <td>Retired</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>#6</td>
        <td>Rank6</td>
        <td>Lothian </td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>Vigilante</td>
        <td>£86,000</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>Unknown</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>#7</td>
        <td>Rank7</td>
        <td>Bedfordshire</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>Housewife</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>#8</td>
        <td>Rank8</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>Policewoman</td>
        <td>$36,000</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>#9</td>
        <td>Rank9</td>
        <td>Lincolnshire</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>Landowner</td>
        <td>Lots</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>#10</td>
        <td>Rank10</td>
        <td>Cheshire</td>
        <td>352</td>
        <td>Arcanist</td>
        <td>A pile of gems</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```